# Python: Running Kivy Designer throws errors

Tags: python, kivy, designer

I wanted to install Kivy Designer. After getting furious with installing all the stuff by myself, I used Kivy Installer from GitHub. It installed python, kivy and designer without any errors, but when I type `python -m designer` in kivy.bat as it's mentioned in tutorial, it throws an error. What may cause the problem?

[image: That's the error]

Comment: Flag as duplicate later, it's a [typo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42603654/5994041). Install a newer wheel and it'll work.

Comment: It doesn't help, I there are no updates for my wheel. I tried to install it on fresh python 2.7.13 and I still have the problem, but this time there is `ImportError: cannot import name SectionConstraint`, with the same logs. Could someone explain Kivy Designer installation more transparently than it is in its docs?

Comment: Newer Kivy wheel, not designer wheel.

Comment: I know, still doesn't help. I just used `python -m pip install wheel` - is it good?

Comment: Ah, ok, as I see you're using my installer, so let's do it from that: run `kivy updatemaster` command and it will update automatically to the latest available wheel.

Comment: Oh, it worked! Thank You. I didn't notice that's your work :D. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Kivy app crashes (release unlocked lock)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42589498/simple-kivy-app-crashes-release-unlocked-lock)