# Simple Kivy app crashes (release unlocked lock)

Tags: kivy

I am getting the following error when trying to run even the simplest of Kivy apps:

```
C:\Users\kprice\Desktop>python test.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\kprice\AppData\Roaming\SPB_16.6\.kivy\logs\kivy_17-03-03_57.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2.dev0, git-9f2daa0, 20170302
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 193 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.3.0 - Build 10.18.15.4256'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 3
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.30 - Build 10.18.15.4256'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <b"WARNING: 0:6: '' :  #version directive missing">
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <b"WARNING: 0:6: '' :  #version directive missing">
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\kprice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 802, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "test.py", line 10, in build
     return Label(text='Hello world')
   File "C:\Users\kprice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\label.py", line 291, in __init__
     self._trigger_texture()
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 75, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.__call__ (kivy\_clock.c:2223)
 RuntimeError: release unlocked lock
```

The code for the app is as follows:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Any ideas on why even the most basic program seems to crash?

Comment: I removed and re-installed Python as I had python 2.7 and python 3.6 installed and I think I jerked up the Kivy install....  Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a [typo](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/commit/848cd0418e611c39e5cc751d6ff83432b07b8529) for a change in the `kivy.clock` code. It basically called the method twice, which it shouldn't (no thread lock to release).

I'm not sure if it's because of Cython or because of Windows, but I believe that error should return a [`ThreadError`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/72dccde884d89586b0cafd990675b7e21720a81f/Modules/_threadmodule.c#L177). There is too small amount of [`RuntimeError`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=runtimeerror&type=Code)s in Kivy, so I'm not sure why does it return a wrong type of error.